# Unable to properly read text from image which has a Color text in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, python-tesseract

What I tried so far. it's working fine most of image which is text black and background is white.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import nltk
import cv2

imageName = "p9.png"
img = cv2.imread(imageName,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #Open the image from which charectors has to be recognized
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert to grey to reduce detials
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17) #Blur to reduce noise
original = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, config='')
print (original)
```

but below image I do not give right text.

[image]

**Output:**

> REMIUM OKING OIL
>
> KETTLE-RENDERED 9s MADE FROM POR siren!
>
> fatworks €)
>
> NET WT. 4 02 (3966)

how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try image thresholding or binarization of the saturation befor applying ```image_to_string```.

Comment: @Lukashou-AGH would you help me to resolve this issue. please.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant is

```
imageName = "p9.png"
img = cv2.imread(imageName,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #Open the image from which charectors has to be recognized
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #convert to grey to reduce detials
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17) #Blur to reduce noise
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,71,2)
#img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
original = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='')
```

Play around with parameters of this function to find what works for you best
`cv2.adaptiveThreshold(src, maxValue, adaptiveMethod, thresholdType, blockSize, C[, dst])`.

I also keep here a link to original tutorial: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html